# Nullable enums don't trigger intellisense for list of valid enum values in C#

Tags: c#, enums, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, nullable

Type this code in C#:

```
ConsoleColor c;

c =
```

As soon as you finish typing `c =`, intellisense presents a list of values from the `ConsoleColor` enum as expected.  Now change it to a nullable:

```
ConsoleColor? c;

c =
```

After you type the `=`, you'd expect intellisense to do the same as before, but it doesn't.  I can't even get the enum list to invoke with `CTRL+SPACE`.  In order to get it intellisense to invoke properly, I have to type `c.Value =`, but that just results in a build error because you can't assign a value to a read-only property.  Oddly, it works as expected in VB.NET:

```
Dim c As ConsoleColor?

c = ConsoleColor.Black
```

Is this just a bug/quirk?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria It's in the tags :)

Comment: Here's the bug reported on MS's site: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760202/nullable-enumeration-types-dont-get-intellisense-auto-complete apparently they're fixing it in Roslyn

Comment: I just tried in VS2013 and no problems.

Comment: @Rik Are you sure? It doesn't work for me in Vs2012. I thought it is by design :(

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It works for me in VS 2012, but *only if* i put a space between the `c` and `=`

Comment: @Rik No, try in two lines. declaration separate and assignment separate. If I do in single line it works for me too.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I am using two lines, too. I meant the second `c`, after the `;`

Comment: @TimS. It's looking like your comment is the correct answer.  I read the report and it's on point with what I am talking about.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** you can probably disregard my answer, since I'm using ReSharper. I forget that sometimes.

Here's a weird thing: 
In VS2012, if I type this:

```
ConsoleColor? c;
c=
```

I get no IntelliSense. If I type this:

```
ConsoleColor? c;
c =
```

I do get IntelliSense. For those who have trouble spotting the difference, it's the space between `c` and `=`. I also need to type another space after the `=` before IntelliSense pops up with suggestions.

Comment: When you say that you get intellisense, are you saying that you see the list of available values in the `ConsoleColor` enum?  I get intellisense, too, but it's as if I just pressed `CTRL+SPACE` on a blank line.

Comment: Shoot, i forgot I'm using ReSharper, that's probably why it works for me.

Comment: You can pretty much find difference between resharper's and Vs's intellisense. There is much difference.